# How to mask date format in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

There is open date `2015-05-19 10:40:14` and close date `2015-05-20 09:21:11`
when I subtract them I am getting (close_date.date_value - open_date.date_value)
some `9.45104166666666666666666666666666666667E-01` value

I want to ignore the time 10:40:14 and 09:21:11 from 2 dates
similarly I am subtracting (SYSDATE - open_date.date_value) and get the number of days in number when I subtract 2 dates

Could anyone help me resolving this problem

```
case
when s then
(close_date.date_value - open_date.date_value)
else
(SYSDATE - open_date.date_value)
end  as "dd",
```

Comment: Please provide example what you need to have. Your result is now 0.9 days. Should it be rounded up or down or something else?

Comment: Why Java, SQL Server?

Comment: @JamesZ: If the closed and open dates are in same day i want it to be rounded as u told

Comment: Use **ROUND** to get rid of the decimal part. Don't use **TRUNC** as it would not use regular **index**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **performance** point of view, I would not use **TRUNC** as it would suppress any regular **index** on the date **column**. I would let the date arithmetic as it is, and **ROUND** the value.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE - to_date('2015-05-20 09:21:11','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') diff,
  2         ROUND(
  3            SYSDATE - to_date('2015-05-20 09:21:11','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  4              ) diff_round
  5  FROM dual;

      DIFF DIFF_ROUND
---------- ----------
29.1248264         29

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  case
  when status_name.list_value_id=9137981352013344123 then
  (TRUNC(close_date.date_value) - TRUNC(open_date.date_value))
  else
  (TRUNC(sysdate) - TRUNC(open_date.date_value))
  end  as "e2e execution time",
```

Comment: (convert(date,close_date.date_value) - convert(date,open_date.date_value))
--          ^-- error here -- ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: I need it for oracle db

Comment: you can use Trunc then

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEDIFF function. Here is the code

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-05-19 10:40:14'), CONVERT(DATETIME, ' 2015-05-20 09:21:11'))
```

Comment: This is SQL Server syntax, not Oracle